# How to use LINQ Like function with group of characters?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How to use LINQ Like function with group of characters?

```
EF.Functions.Like("abc", "[a-c]bc"); //false
EF.Functions.Like("123", "[0-9][0-9][0-9]"); //false
```

The above functions appear to not work. What am I missing?

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp I am not.

Comment: Which database engine are you targetting?

Comment: @mwal: Documentation on `EF.Functions.Like` is more pertinent here. Just because SQL can do something doesn't mean that EF knows how to translate from one to the other.

Comment: That explains it. I am targeting SQL Server.

Comment: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-3.1) claims "The pattern which may involve wildcards %,_,[,],^."
Personally, I like to write my own SQL.